# Desktop icons tab below are white

Tags: windows-xp, desktop-search

I don't remember what I did, but the text tab below the icons are all white. It is a PC running XP

Answer (score 0):

You may have changed something in the Advanced display options
Right click on the desktop, and choose properties. Load back the Windows theme(default)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Start > Control panel > System > Advanced > The first Settings button from the first section (I think "Features")
2. Check if the last but one option (something about label shadows of desktop icons) is uncheck. If so, check it. Then do "Ok" and "Ok".